# PHP find if numbers contained in a string are present in another string

Tags: php, match

Hi,

I have one string like this:

```
4,21
```

and the other like this:

```
,4,5,6,14,21,22,
```

I need to find out if any of the numbers contained in the first string are present in the second string but since each number is separated by a comma Im a little confused. What function should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: `explode()` your array and get the intersection of both arrays with `array_intersect()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert each string into arrays.

Try this:

```
$str1 = "4,21";
$array1 = explode(",", $str1);

$str2 = "4,5,6,14,21,22";
$array2 = explode(",", $str2);  

$common = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

echo "Common numbers:<br/>";
echo implode(",", $common);
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats my answer.